# openerp 7 start message "no module named pooler"

Tags: module, odoo

Error message as below when start, pls help,thanks

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/openerp-server", line 5, in 
> >         openerp.cli.main()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/cli/**init**.py",
>   line 51, in main
>       **import**(m)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py",
>   line 133, in load_module
>       mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/account_test/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import account_test
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/account_test/account_test.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       import pooler
>
> ImportError: No module named pooler

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating new module, and in that you have importd the pooler.
as per the solution change the import statement

```
import pooler
```

to

```
from openerp import pooler
```

in line 32 of `account_test.py`.